# How to use google map API with MFC or QT in c++ language?

Tags: c++, google-maps, mfc

I have a question how to use google map api in my developing program.

My program is being implemented by c++ language in Visual studio 2017 environment and MFC for graphical interface in usual.

I want to develop program of two versions using google map api.
The first one is to use the google map in my program without internet connection.
The second one is with internet connection.

If anyone know how to do it, please answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Qt C++ provides a QWebChannel, which fills the gap between C++ applications and HTML/JavaScript applications.

You need to create a QWebChannel and register a JavaScript helper Object in C++. This object exposes public methods, which are invokable calling from JavaScript in HTML.

QWebEngineView::setUrl() hosts a page, which has Google Maps.
QWebEnginePage::runJavaScript() gives you the power of manipulating the map. C++ call JS, and JS call C++ --- this is truly powerful!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same need as yours. The solution I have found was to use an embedded browsing component and from that component access Google Maps.
See my [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1225511/Integrating-with-Google-Maps-via-a-Desktop-Applica) about this implementation.
Basically, here are the instructions for adding such component to your MFC application:

1. Open Visual C++ and follow these steps:
2. Choose New from the File menu.
3. Select MFC AppWizard (exe).
4. Enter the project name and select a location.
5. Click OK. When the dialog box for Step 1 appears, select the application type that is appropriate for your application—single document, multiple document, or dialog-based. Select "Dialog-based" for this example.
6. Click Next.
   Select application features and support.
   The dialog box for Step 2 asks you to select any features and support your application will need—an About box or automation support, for example. The WebBrowser control is an ActiveX control, so select ActiveX Controls. Click Next to go to the next step.
7. Select the project style.
   The dialog box for Step 3 is used to define your project. You have only one project style option, Standard MFC. But you can indicate whether you want the IDE to generate comments in the source code, and you can specify how you want to use the MFC library. The default selections are appropriate for most applications. Click Next to go to the next step. Name the files and classes. The dialog box for Step 4 displays the names of all the files and classes that Visual C++ created. You can change these to more descriptive names or to names required by your specification. Click Finish.
8. Add a WebBrowser control.

The actual part that interface with Google Maps is embedded within an HTML code that should be also hosted, so my solution combines the browser's hosting with the interface with Google Maps.

The HTML code is formatted in this example:

```
HTML_TEXT.Format(L"<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv=\"IE X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE = edge\"><body><div id =\"googleMap\" style=\"width:%dpx;height:%dpx\"><script>function myMap(){var mapProp = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f), zoom : 10};var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"googleMap\"), mapProp);marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f),map: map});}</script><script src = \"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%s&callback=myMap\"></script></div></body></html>", w, h, Latitude, Longitude, Latitude, Longitude, API_KEY);
```

As you can see, you can generate a map with a marker pointing on a given location using **Longitude** and **Latitude**. You also need to [obtain an API_KEY from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Comment: Thank you for your answering.  But I failed to make a success to do it. Please let me know your knowhow step by step(ex. where is the place to write down a code). In fact, I wrote down your code(ex. calling WriteHTML func., Method2) in the generated dialog's OnInitDialog() function. The weird thing is when I call WriteHTML, m_Browser.get_Document() does not get any object pointer. Can you help me more? I have one more question. Have you tried in Visual studio 2017?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. That's because I got a free license from Microsoft after being invited to join BizSpark. If you send me your code to haephrati@gmail.com I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks. When you send source code always remove the temporary and huge files such as .sdf